# How can I view Timing Events from Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to track performance data on a website with google analytics universal.

My code is the following :

```
<script>
    // Newly created gmail account : univ.analytics@gmail.com
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-47517126-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    // Google Analytics Universal Tracking timing event Test
    ga('send', 'timing', 'metrics', 'run', 37);
    var journal = {
        run: 37,
        fetch: 601,
        dom: 210,
        total: 818
    };
    ga('send', 'event', 'metrics', 'journal', journal);
</script>
```

I am receiving events, but i can't see submitted values.

[image: google analytics events]

I can't see the timing event in google analytics reporting panel.

I'm able to click on an event category (metrics) and an event action (journal) but I can't see the object uploaded from the reporting interface.

Any hint ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can pass an object into an event label. The [event parameters are all strings](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#overview), unless it's a value and then it's a number.

Comment: You can however create custom dimensions and store these values with every event sent.